# It is possible to add cv2.polylines box to ORB?

Tags: python, opencv, orb

How can I add a perspective tracking box around the trainimage?

I'm using ORB:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('box.png',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('box_in_scene.png',0) # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
orb = cv2.ORB()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
```

Who can I draw the box in ORB like this:[image]

Comment: compute the perspective homography from your matching and use warpPerspective or perspectiveTransform on the tracking box (depends on how teacking box reference is given)

Comment: Thanks Micka! Could you provide a link with an example?

Comment: sorry, no python code from me and I have no link. But using google looks like this is exactly what you want to do: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html